# VueJs updating select-boxes accordingly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am looking for right solution to update multi select box based on each select option.

## Logic

[image: one]

Based on image above i want to **change options (list gets fresh each time "no .push()")** of `select 1,3,4,5` when i select option in `select 2` and so on.

> Data of `select 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` will be return from back-end when i select any option of any select box. so there will be always values to replace with current ones.

## Issue

My current code pushes data to other select boxes but the issue is sometimes my returned data (data that will be pushed) aren't array they are object (it supposed to act as single option) but they return with several empty options (image below is a sample of that)

[image: two]

#### Sample returned data

```
data: {id: 54, option_id: 1, cable_id: 1, name: "etsahetahe", description: "sthsthrt", position: "Kabel Udara",…}
    id: 54
    name: "etsahetahe"
    description: "sthsthrt"
    option_id: 1
    created_at: "2020-04-27T08:05:06.000000Z"
    updated_at: "2020-04-27T08:05:06.000000Z"
        option: {id: 1, segment_id: 2, cable_id: 2, type: "Backbone", site_name: "12585444-54741115",…}
            id: 1
            type: "Backbone"
            segment_id: 2
            site_name: "12585444-54741115"
            created_at: "2020-04-14T03:51:47.000000Z"
            updated_at: "2020-04-15T08:03:32.000000Z"
                segment: {id: 2, hthree_id: 1, name: "Segment 2", created_at: "2020-04-14T03:36:50.000000Z",…}
                        hthree: {id: 1, area_id: 1, name: "h3i 1", created_at: "2020-04-14T03:36:23.000000Z",…}
                    hthree_id: 1
                    id: 2
                    name: "Segment 2"
                    created_at: "2020-04-14T03:36:50.000000Z"
                    updated_at: "2020-04-14T03:36:50.000000Z"
message: "Data retrieved successfully."
```

> Here for instance in my returned data, `segment` is object and not array of data, therefore I need this object as single option in my select box.

## Code

https://jsfiddle.net/robertnicjoo/xc5f2btL/2/

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      option:{
        zone:'',
        area:'',
        city:'',
        segment:'',
        link:'',
        closure:'',
      },
      zones: [],
      links: [],
      areas: [],
      regions: [],
      segments: [],
      closures: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getData();
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      this.axios.get("/api/maps")
        .then((res) => {
          this.zones = res.data.data;
          this.links = res.data.links;
          this.areas = res.data.areas;
          this.regions = res.data.regions;
          this.segments = res.data.segments;
          this.closures = res.data.closures;
        })
    },
    zoneChange(val, e) {
      axios.post('/api/admin/maps/valChanger', {
          [val]: e
        })
        .then(res => {

          if (val == 'zone') {
            this.areas = res.data.data.areas;
            this.segments = res.data.data.segments;
            this.links = res.data.data.links;
            let links = res.data.data.links;
            for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
              this.closures = [...links[i].closures]
            }
            this.regions = res.data.data.cities;
          }
          if (val == 'area') {
            this.zones = res.data.data.zone;
            this.segments = res.data.data.segments;
            this.links = res.data.data.links;
            let links = res.data.data.links;
            for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
              this.closures = [...links[i].closures]
            }
            this.regions = res.data.data.cities;
          }
          if (val == 'city') { // has issue
            this.areas = res.data.data.area;
            this.zones = res.data.data.area.zone;
            this.links = res.data.data.links;
            this.closures = res.data.data.links.closures;
            this.segments = res.data.data.segments;
          }
          if (val == 'segment') { // has issue
            this.areas = res.data.data.hthree;
            this.zones = res.data.data.hthree.area.zone;
            this.links = res.data.data.links;
            let links = res.data.data.links;
            for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
              this.closures = [...links[i].closures]
            }
          }
          if (val == 'link') { //has issue
            this.closures = res.data.data.closures;
            this.segments = res.data.data.segment;
            this.regions = res.data.data.segment.hthree;
            this.areas = res.data.data.segment.area;
            this.zones = res.data.data.segment.area.zone;
          }
          if (val == 'closure') {
            this.regions = res.data.data.link.segment.hthree;
            this.segments = res.data.data.link.segment;
            this.zones = res.data.data.link.segment.hthree.area.zone;
            this.areas = res.data.data.link.segment.hthree.area;
            this.links = res.data.data.link;
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          var errors = error.response.data;
          let errorsHtml = '<ol>';
          $.each(errors.errors, function(k, v) {
            errorsHtml += '<li>' + v + '</li>';
          });
          errorsHtml += '</ol>';

          this.$notify.error({
            title: 'Filter Error',
            dangerouslyUseHTMLString: true,
            message: errorsHtml
          });
        });
    },
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.el-select {
  float: right;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <el-row :gutter="10">
    <el-card shadow="always">
      <el-form ref="option" :model="option" label-width="120">
        <el-col :span="24">
          <el-form-item label="Zone">
            <el-select align="right" @change="zoneChange('zone', $event)" v-model="option.zone" placeholder="Pilih Zone Region">
              <el-option v-for="zone in zones" :key="zone.id" :label="zone.name" :value="zone.id">
              </el-option>
            </el-select>
          </el-form-item>
        </el-col>
        <el-col :span="24">
          <el-form-item label="Area">
            <el-select @change="zoneChange('area', $event)" placeholder="Pilih Area" v-model="option.area">
              <el-option v-for="area in areas" :key="area.id" :label="area.name" :value="area.id">
              </el-option>
            </el-select>
          </el-form-item>
        </el-col>
        <el-col :span="24">
          <el-form-item label="Region">
            <el-select @change="zoneChange('city', $event)" placeholder="Pilih Kota" v-model="option.city">
              <el-option v-for="region in regions" :key="region.id" :label="region.name" :value="region.id">
              </el-option>
            </el-select>
          </el-form-item>
        </el-col>
        <el-col :span="24">
          <el-form-item label="Segment">
            <el-select @change="zoneChange('segment', $event)" placeholder="Pilih Segment" v-model="option.segment">
              <el-option v-for="segment in segments" :key="segment.id" :label="segment.name" :value="segment.id">
              </el-option>
            </el-select>
          </el-form-item>
        </el-col>
        <el-col :span="24">
          <el-form-item label="Link">
            <el-select @change="zoneChange('link', $event)" placeholder="Pilih Link" v-model="option.link">
              <el-option v-for="link in links" :key="link.id" :label="link.site_name" :value="link.id">
              </el-option>
            </el-select>
          </el-form-item>
        </el-col>
        <el-col :span="24">
          <el-form-item label="Closure">
            <el-select @change="zoneChange('closure', $event)" placeholder="Pilih Closure" v-model="option.closure">
              <el-option v-for="closure in closures" :key="closure.id" :label="closure.name" :value="closure.id">
              </el-option>
            </el-select>
          </el-form-item>
        </el-col>
        <el-col :span="18" :offset="3">
          <el-button type="primary" icon="el-icon-search" round>Search</el-button>
        </el-col>
      </el-form>
    </el-card>
  </el-row>
</div>
```

> In `zoneChange(val, e) {..}` function I am trying to rewrite default values of all select boxes based on selected option. As I explained in issue part it return with extra empty options sometimes.

## Question

What is the best approach for me to make my logic happen? using `watch method` or my current method is good just need to be fixed?

Please share your solutions with me.

Comment: I am not aure why you need watch, you can update the values of other selects and have in the function that handles the change which effects the other selects a validation. function which will clear out the empty values and check/fix the shape of the data.

Comment: @Michael well `watch` was just a question as i wasn't sure if i need it. and about function i have `zoneChange(val, e) {` which does exactly as you suggested. there is issue with it tho that i explained in issue part. any idea on that?

Comment: Why can't you remove the "extra empty options"?

Comment: @Michael for first reason: i am not sure why they are there in general :)) second: i think i should change those object into array?? not sure about it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

in order to avoid extra options I turned my object data into array with this code

```
const newObj = [ res.data.data.link.segment]
this.segments = newObj;
```

Hope it can help others.